# Convert Mono to list

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have this Mono list:

```
Mono<List<MasterPair>> list;
```

Into MasterPair I have a `Long id;`

How I can convert the list like this:

```
Mono<List<Long>> list;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unroll it, map, then reroll it into a List.

```
list
.flatMapIterable(v -> v)
.map(v -> v.id)
.collectList()
```